# Detect source of value change in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-handler

I've have this handler

`<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.foo}" action="{!c.baz}"/>`

Is there a way to know whether the value was modified from button click (via component.set(), etc) versus modified from input field?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is directly.

I assume you want to perform different actions based on what caused it?

If so, it would be best to either directly call the method you want to occur, in a helper method or using the `<aura:method>` registration, when you use `component.set()` in your code.

If you do that then the button click will have its own logic keeping everything separate.

Comment: I think that's right. When you put an `aura:handler` on a component, the event argument that gets passed to the client-side controller function for that handler's action always seems to have that component's `aura:id` as the `event.getSource().getLocalId()` no matter how the attribute value is updated.